# Using Velocity with Tiles and Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, velocity, tiles2

I'm presently using `Spring 3.0.4` and `Apache Tiles 2.2.2` in my web app. I'd like to replace JSP with `Apache Velocity 1.6.3` but I'm somewhat confused on how to do this. Ultimately, I'd like to be able to do the following in a Tiles definition:

```
<definition name="basicLayout" template="/WEB-INF/layout/basicLayout.vm">
    <put-attribute name="header" value="/WEB-INF/layout/header.vm" />
    <put-attribute name="content-area" value="/WEB-INF/layout/content.vm" />
    <put-attribute name="footer" value="/WEB-INF/layout/footer.vm" />
</definition>
```

Is this possible? If so, do I need to create any custom view classes to support it? I'm currently using the standard Spring VelocityConfigurer, TilesConfigurer, VelocityView, TilesView classes.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen section 16.4 of the spring reference documentation? http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html

Answer (score 2):

I've created helper classes which include tiles integration with velocity:
https://github.com/pete911/openhouse-web
there's a descritption when you scroll down. classes can be found in maven central as well.

Answer (score 0):

inside your servlet definition you need the following:

```
    <bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView
    </value>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

as you can see you declare tiles.xml ..this is the file that will hold the definiotion name etc.

if you are using maven you need the following dependencies:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
        <artifactId>tiles-template</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```